# Is there any way to easily link a file in RDoc?

Tags: ruby, documentation, markup, rdoc

I want to link to a documentation of a file in RDoc. but the only way I could do is with the following markup:

```
configuration.rb[link:files/configuration_rb.html]
```

I would like to do it in a better way, something like this:

```
<file>configuration.rb</file>
```

Is there any existing markup rule to do this?

**EDIT**: of course I've tried without any markup like this `configuration.rb` but it shows the filename without the link :(

Answer (score 7):

#### To display a link in rdoc

```
{Link label}[url ]
```

#### Sample

```
{Killer question}[http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230954/is-there-any-way-to-easily-link-a-file-in-rdoc]
```

will create a link of the this question

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asks about relative links, not an external URL. In addition, what is `http://http://`?

Answer (score 2):

> Auto hyperlinked:  MyClass 
>   my_class.rb  def my_method; end; 
>   #my_method  http:, mailto:, ftp:, www.  link: (to local filesystem relative to
>   --op)  (urls to images are rendered as inline image tags)  label[url] (uses
>   label as hyperlink text)  {multi word
>   label}[url] (uses label as hyperlink
>   text)
>
> Ruby:
>
> ClassNames, source_files.rb and
>   either
>   method_name_having_an_underscore   or
>   #methodnamewithhash are hyperlinked to their documentation.

It sounds like you're looking for that second one, but I've never used it before so I can't give you a fully useful example.

Comment: Well.. I guess your last option is to add the markup you want and submit a patch? Or put in a feature request, at least.

Comment: yeah, it looks like you're right. so right now it's not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Try not to use markup at all.

Look at [RDoc's own documentation](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html), they have similar links in the "Roadmap" paragraph. They markup is [here](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/lib/rdoc/README?revision=15018&view=markup).

Magic!